# Unable to load certain websites in ubuntu

Tags: browser

The website coursera.org does not load. After sometime it displays a message, "Please use a modern browser with JavaScript enabled to use Coursera.". This happens with both the browsers I use, firefox and chrome.

javascript has not been disabled in either of the browsers.

I have the same problem with random websites with tennis.com being notable, as I access it a lot.

The loading of the websites usually gets to a point where the status bar tells , "Connecting to ...." or "Waiting for ...".

This problem is only with my ubuntu installation. The websites load fine when I attempt to access them from windows.

Could you help me troubleshoot this. This has been particularly bothersome for me as I am taking a [MOOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course) from coursera.

EDIT
After seeing a solution to a similar problem, I tried accessing coursera.org, tennis.com and foxnews.com through the proxy, daveproxy.co.uk. While tennis.com and foxnews.com loaded through the proxy, coursera.org still says, ""Please use a modern browser with JavaScript enabled to use Coursera."

Comment: In Chrome, try pressing `<F12>` and clicking **Console** to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @Dennis, coursera.org is suddenly loading in chrome. tennis.com isn't. The console says, "Failed to load resource http://cdn.tennis.com/static/assets/stylesheets/main.css?v=0201
Failed to load resource http://use.typekit.net/eiv0nll.js". It's still trying though.

Comment: Coursera does no user agent checking. The *Please use a modern browser...*  message gets removed with a simple JavaScript instruction unless your browser is IE 7. The only way I can see how this could fail is that the [external script](https://dt5zaw6a98blc.cloudfront.net/site-static/64ba6f262fa759c2615417022b52293e7b0fb784/js/core/require.js) could not be loaded.

Comment: @Dennis, Do you have any idea as to why that external script could not be loading?

Comment: There are many possibilities. It might be a simple problem with the CDN. How many times did it work in Windows? How many times did it not work in Ubuntu?

Comment: It always works in windows. It has never in ubuntu.

Comment: Odd. Try disabling *Use a web service...*, *Use a prediction service...* and *Predict network actions...* in `chrome://settings/`. Those cause issues sometimes. Verify that you don't have a proxy set in Ubuntu. Also, if this happens again, check the console for error messages.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7469/discussion-between-abhijith-and-dennis)

Comment: "Do you have any idea as to why that external script could not be loading?" - Also ensure that no ad/script-blocker add-on/extension is responsible.

Answer (score 0):

I dont advice you to use firefox when visiting coursera.org because some feature are not supported yet such as the speed change for video.

I had the same problem , I solved it by using google chrome (chromium) but you will need to install the chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra package to make the videos work in Chromium.

You can get it [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra)

Comment: cousera.org is suddenly loading on chromium. :-|

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: It wasn't until yesterday in chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below instructions from http://enable-javascript.com/

1. In the address bar, type about:config and press Enter.
2. Click "I'll be careful, I promise" if a warning message appears.
3. In the search box, search for javascript.enabled
4. Toggle the "javascript.enabled" preference (right-click and select "Toggle" or double-click the preference) to change the value from "false" to "true".
5. Click on the "Reload current page" button of the web browser to refresh the page.

Hope it works !!!

Comment: Why would he have JavaScript disabled in the first place?

Comment: ^ especially as he said "javascript has not been disabled in either of the browsers."